# In PHP, What is $var [] [] means?

Tags: php

I found this `$css['misc/vertical-tabs.css']['data']` when reading Drupal book. I googled it but did not quite get the exact result.

I would like to know what does it mean `"$var [] []"`?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: "As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []." http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

`$css` is an array containing an element named `'misc/vertical-tabs.css'` which is itself an array that contains an element named `'data'`

Answer (score 1):

Its a `2-D array` in php, read more about [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
$test = array(
             array('swapnesh')
            );

echo $test[0][0]; // output- swapnesh
```

Answer (score 1):

Brackets define array keys.

Example: `$array[key][key]` and so forth. It gets more complicated than that past 2 levels, but this is a fairly simple paradigm:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well it's simply a 2-D array. For example, if you want to group certain things that assosiate to somethings together you might use this.

For example, `$person['john']['age'] = 10; $person['john']['gender'] = 'male';....$person['john']['weight'] = '40kg'`.